# How to describe an error that occurs when your reference standard is falsely positive?

Tags: error, accuracy, diagnostic

Here's sort of a TL;DR: how would you call it, if you incorrectly say your test was "false negative", because in fact the reference standard got it wrong (and was false positive).

So my new test is actually correct, because the reference standard got it wrong, which obviously results in a serious underestimation of my sensitivity...

Does this have a name? I was looking at type III errors, but I don't think this is it...

And here's the longer version of my question:

So I have this test, it's actually a PET-scan, something we use to diagnose infectious disease. I'm using it to look at heart valves, to see if they are infected. If a heart valve is infected, we say the patient has "endocarditis", regardless of which of the 4 valves is infected.

Now here's my problem:
- I've defined the patients in my database as having either endocarditis (1) or not (0), based on the reference standard
- But with the PET-scan, we look at the 4 heart valves individually. One of the valves may be positive, which, in case of a positive reference standard, is a true positive. However, rarely 2 or more valves are affected, so for the other 3 valves, the PET will be "false negative", even though the PET-scan is probably correct, since it even identified the valve that is affected (which the reference standard cannot).

How would I describe the error that occurs if we were to analyze our data on a per-valve basis. I want to use this in my scientific paper, to clarify why we did the analysis on a per-patient basis, and why we excluded the other 3 valves if a patient had a positive PET-scan of one of his valves.

Hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to re-run the tests to fix this. Have you considered summarising the results by heart rather than valve and recalculating the confusion matrix?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that we also use quantitative measurements of each valve. Let me illustrate one of the problems I've been having: a patient has 2 heart valves that we looked at. The patient did NOT have the disease (0). One valve had a measured score of 1.2, the other valve had a measured score of 1.4. Now, since we chose a patient-based approach, which measurement should I use for this true-negative patient? Taking the average of the two hardly seems right...

Comment: Those are continuous values. What value does a valve need to be considered a 'yes' for the disease?

Comment: That we don't know. That's also something we're trying to figure out using ROC curves with AUC and Youden's J statistic.

Comment: But for now, the variable that determines whether a valve is a yes or a no for the disease, is the observer's visual impression, i.e. verdict of the observer, not based on any quantitative score.

Comment: To say something is a true positive is to say that the model correctly predicted its positive status. Here's the scorecard "Reality = has disease, Prediction = has disease". But if you do not know whether the disease is predicted, you have an empty scorecard "Reality = has disease, Model = don't know exactly"